# Fixed Positioned Menu Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to get a horizontal menu to be fixed in its current position so it doesn't move when you scroll in both regular view and also responsive view. 
I tried researching how to do it but couldnt seem to have luck in making it work.
This is on a Wordpress site,
[This Wordpress Site](http://nypsi.com/menu-test/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few styles with !important that are holding you back. Namely `position: relative !important;` and `width: auto !important;`

Try adding (or separating out) these styles to this class:

```
.responsive nav.art-nav, .responsive .art-nav-inner {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Ideally just on the nav not .art-nav-inner i don't know what that is affecting

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed what you suggested on the style.responsive.css and it didnt do anything. I have not changed it back

Comment: You remove the !important styles in the css under that class?

Comment: No, sorry, doing that now.

Comment: The !importants have been removed.

Comment: .art-nav .desktop-nav { position: fixed;}

Comment: .art-nav-inner { position: static; }

Comment: Its locked in place on desktop view(not responsive) but got moved to the far center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your 'style.css' sheet (there are several ways to get to it) and add this to the bottom:

```
.art-nav, .responsive nav.art-nav, .responsive .art-nav-inner {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

Few things this does:
1. Fixes your menu in place on scroll.
2. Extends your menu to full width of the screen (just looks a little better.)
3. Does this all screen sizes (desktop, tablet, and mobile.)

Hope that works for you.